# login authentication alert message not rendering in ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im authenticating using phone number received as parameter in api to retrieve data from the specific user. Right now I simply want to handle situations when the api receives a number that is not in the api. For that im using material ui alert to display to the user, but im still getting the error ( Cannot read property 'user' of undefined) and not the alert in the UI when i input wrong number. Here is the code:

```
 const Login = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    const location = useLocation()
    const [state, setState] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const phone = state
    ...
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));

    const handleClick = () => {
       getData();
    };

    const getData = async () => {
       const a = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: headers });
       const response = await a.json();
       const respData = response.user[0].attributes[0]
       setData(respData);
       history.push(`/user/${respData.name}`)
    };

    const onTextChange = event => {
       setState(event.target.value);
    }
    

    return (
       <div>
          <input onChange={onTextChange}>
          <Button onClick={handleClick} >
             login
          </Button>
    

         {(data.user || []).map((data) => 
            (data.length == 0) ? (
              <Alert severity="error" className={styles.alert}>
                Incorrect phone number . Try again!
              </Alert>
            ) : (
              <></>
            )
         )}
      </div>
     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `try/catch` block arround the place you `await` your request and do your error handling there (that is, not use `response.user[0].attributes[0]` upon HTTP error response and avoid *Cannot read property 'user' of undefined* runtime error). You will enter the `catch` block if you return response error code in your backend.

```
try {
   const a = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: headers });
   const response = await a.json();
   const respData = response.user[0].attributes[0]
   setData(respData);
   history.push(`/user/${respData.name}`)
}
catch (err) {
  setShowAlert(true);
  // some more error handling if necessary
}
```

I would recommend to have a boolean flag in the state or if it's more complex to decide, a function to indicate whether to show or not the alert. It will simplify your logic in the view a lot. Something like:

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
...
{showAlert && 
<Alert severity="error" className={styles.alert}>
    Incorrect phone number . Try again!
</Alert>}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of errors in the above question. Due to first error it should not compile.

- `input` tag is not closed. `<input />`
- `data` is an object and not array. you are checking length of data object. And even if it's an array with length 0 then you need if-else expression rather then map. Map will not be called in your case.

```
{!!data.user.length && (
<Alert severity="error" className={styles.alert}>
An alert message to user!
</Alert>
)}
```

Last <></> will not be needed in that case.